# Can `get_mpz_t()` be omitted somehow?

Tags: c++, gmp

I've been calling `get_mpz_t()` a lot on `mpz_class` types. I don't really get it's point. I have red the [documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html) and from what I can tell, it's needed just because some functions require `mpz_t` and not `mpz_class`?

To copy the example given in the documentation, I find I often call it in a situation like this but with various functions:

```
mpz_class a, b, c;
...
mpz_gcd (a.get_mpz_t(), b.get_mpz_t(), c.get_mpz_t());
```

If the only difference is the syntax, can it be omitted or automated so I don't have to type it as much? I am much more familiar with C++ than C.

Comment: Why have you tagged this C?

Comment: @klutt I thought maybe the answer had to do with being compatible with C.

Comment: Hard to get it compatible with C if you're using classes ;)

Comment: You could derive your own class from `mpz_class` and give that class an `operator mpz_t`. However, that would still not provide you with a direct conversion from `mpz_class`, because you'd then have two user-defined conversions.

Comment: For this example you should just write `a=gcd(b,c)`. There should not be that many functions that require going through the C interface (mulmod is the most common because (a*b)%c does not expand to mulmod).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not write your own wrapper function?

```
inline void mpz_gcd(mpz_class& a, const mpz_class& b, const mpz_class& c)
{
    mpz_gcd(a.get_mpz_t(), b.get_mpz_t(), c.get_mpz_t());
}
```

Given that this is C++ you can even give the wrapper function the same name as the original.

Comment: Thanks. Though I find I call it on a lot of different functions, e.g. mod pow, perfect power etc. I was more wondering if someone could confirm my understanding it's just syntax is correct?

Comment: @northerner The authors could have written it so that there is an automatic conversion from `mpz_class` to `mpz_t` (or `mpz_ptr` or `mpz_srcptr`) but enabling such automatic conversions often introduces ambiguities into code. Maybe that was the reason.

Comment: What is the point of having both `mpz_class` and `mpz_t` in the library?

Comment: `mpz_t` is C compatible, but requires you to manage memory yourself. The `mpz_class` was written in C++ to free you from memory management, but it's a layer on top of `mpz_t` rather than a total rewrite. So both exist because they serve different needs.